# Access the request path variable from an error gson view?

Tags: rest, grails, groovy

I have a RESTful api build around a simple user (grails) domain class like this one:

```
class User{
    Long id
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

And I also have built a controller class for that user:

```
class UserController extends RestfulController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    UserController() {
        super(User)
    }
}
```

Grails generates all the "regular crud endpoints" for me, which is nice but I want to modify the regular 404 error for a new one with the user id which can be found as a path variable (resource's id), for example:

```
www.url/user/3
```

If there is no user with id 3, I want this json error response:

```
{"errorMessage":"user 3 not found"}
```

To achieve this, I have modified the 404 gson view:

response.status 404

```
json {
    message "User ${request.PATHVARIABLE} not found."
    error 404
}
```

This is partially working because my custom json message is shown but I can't manage to access the path variable on the view, I know that I can access the request but I don't find a valid method that returns the path variable on that request (the PATHVARIABLE method shown on the example below it's just an example, not a real method).

Can I access this id from the gson error view somehow?

UPDATE:
in my view, if I try to get the request uri:

```
json {
    uri request.uri
    params params
    message "User ${params.id} not found."
    error 404 
}
```

When I try to get a user that does not exist with /user/123, this is my response:

```
{
    "uri": "/error",
    "params": {
        "parameterMap": {},
        "empty": true
    },
    "message": "User null not found.",
    "error": 404
}
```

why the request uri is /error instead of my original request uri?

Comment: An option would be to do `request.uri.split('/').last()` - but it makes a lot of assumptions about your uri (which may be ok in your case)

Comment: I already have though that before but I don't want to parse the uri that way, In spring there are ways to get the path variable, can't I do the same in grails?

Comment: In spring what object are you getting it from?

Comment: Just looked at the api of `HttpView` and it has the parsed `params` object - so posted an answer. Just tested on Grails 3.3.8 & Views 1.2.8

Answer (score 1):

The json view will have a `params` object so you can do:

```
json {
    if (params.id) {
        message "User ${params.id} not found."
    } else {
        message "Not found."
    }
    error 404
}
```

Comment: is not working for me, when I do a GET call to user/1 the message is: "User null not found"

Comment: Try `json { params params }` to get a full dump of your params to debug.

Comment: there ir nothing:
{
    "params": {
        "parameterMap": {},
        "empty": true
    },
    "message": "User null not found.",
    "error": 404
}

Comment: I have updated the question in case, in case it helps you to see what's happening